# Check if multi dictionary contains a value Swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift, function, dictionary

I want to check if multi dictionary contains a value for example
Below is all my code:

```
struct listBuyItem: Codable {

    let id: Int
    let beer: String
    let quantity: Int
    let totalPrice: Double


}

var cart: [listBuyItem] = [listBuyItem]()

cart.append(listBuyItem(id: beer.id, beer: beer.beerName, quantity: Int((cell?.stepperBeer.value ?? Double(0))), totalPrice: price))
```

how can I check if "id = 1" exist?

Comment: That's an array of dictionaries, not a dictionary. So naming it "dict" is misleading. Then use `contains(where:)`: `let id1IsPresent = array.contains(where: { $0["id"] == 1 }`?

Comment: That's not Swift code. Please post a compiling example.

Comment: A re-write of the solution suggested by Larme since the question has changed, `let id1IsPresent = cart.contains(where: { $0.id == 1 }`

Comment: That's more efficient. This works too: `cart.map(\.id).contains(1)`. Your question is not about dictionaries though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
for eachCart in cart {
    if eachCart.id == 1 {
         print("id is equal to 1")
    }
}
```

Comment: Codable is a typealias of encodable and decodable but that does not mean that you can't loop throught it. It does only enable you to decode and encode the object. Try this and please say what errors come if you encounter any.

Comment: at "if dict.contains" I receive this error: "Value of type 'listBuyItem' has no member 'contains' "

Comment: could you please show more code. It's quite hard to figure it out with this little code. Thanks!

Comment: Greate thanks! I have now updated my answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: The best! Thank You!